# Sort by number of document associated

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have two collection, identities and interventions. And identity has many interventions. I have to sort by three types : at first there is identities with active intervention, then identities with inactive interventions and at last identities without interventions. Each types have to be sorted by alphabetical order.

Here is the data I hase :

```
> db.identities.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba0377656280a1000008"),
        "screenname" : "User without intervention 1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba0677656280a100000c"),
        "screenname" : "User with inactive intervention 2"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba49776562aca000076b"),
        "screenname" : "User with active intervention 1"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c432fa776562356200011a"),
        "screenname" : "User with active intervention 2"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba49776562aca000076b"),
        "screenname" : "User without intervention 2"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c42cc7776562209500006a"),
        "screenname" : "User with inactive intervention 1"
}

> db.interventions.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c4448a7765622817000045"),
        "identity_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba0377656280a1000008"),
        "active" : true
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c44a1b77656282f0000451"),
        "identity_id" : ObjectId("56c42f54776562b78a00032f"),
        "active" : false
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c450c8776562336a000776"),
        "identity_id" : ObjectId("56c432fa776562356200011a"),
        "active" : true
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c450c8776562336a000776"),
        "identity_id" : ObjectId("56c42cc7776562209500006a"),
        "active" : false
}
```

I expect to have the this results :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba49776562aca000076b"),
        "screenname" : "User with active intervention 1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c432fa776562356200011a"),
        "screenname" : "User with active intervention 2"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba49776562aca000076b"),
        "screenname" : "User with inactive intervention 1"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba0677656280a100000c"),
        "screenname" : "User with inactive intervention 2"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba0377656280a1000008"),
        "screenname" : "User without intervention 1"
}
{       
        "_id" : ObjectId("56c2ba49776562aca000076b"),
        "screenname" : "User without intervention 2"
}
```

I'm not very competent with MongoDb. At the moment, I have just :

```
db['domain_test#identities'].aggregate({ $project: { screenname: { $toLower: "$screenname" } } }, {$sort: { screenname: 1 }})
```

It just sort by screenname but does not check the other table. I suppose I have to add other values to `$project` but I have no idea how.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: your _id s have duplicates, and you can simply sort results by `db.identities.find().sort({screenname:1})`

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Comment: @Saravana sorry for duplicates. It wasn't just a copy/paste, I edited the data. If just sorting by screenname works in this case, it's just a coincidence. I want to have users with active intervention first, then users with inactive interventions then users without interventions.

Comment: @Veeram I have mongo 3.4.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

Use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get the matched interventions array ( one to one ) with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) in `$addFields` to output first element.

Use [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) to locate the position of searched boolean value in list of values, which is just 0 or 1 with -1 for missing field followed by [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to keep the output index in the extra field in the document and descending [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) on sort field to sort the document.

[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields-from-output-documents) with exclusion to drop the sort field and intervention to get expected output.

```
db.identities.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"interventions",
    "localField":"_id",
    "foreignField":"identity_id",
    "as":"interventions"
  }},
  {"$addFields":{
    "sortorder":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{"intervention":{"$arrayElemAt":["$interventions",0]}},
        "in":{"$indexOfArray":[[false,true],"$$intervention.active"]}
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$sort":{"sortorder":-1}},
  {"$project":{"sortorder":0,"interventions":0}}
])
```